# Pivot wide to long in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table

I need to pivot a matrix in R, and I'm a little stumped as to exactly the right way to get what I want. I'm sure pivot_longer  is probably the answer, but I can't figure it out.

My current dataframe looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(c(1,2),c(4,5),c(2,3),c(5,4))
names(d) <- (c("treat1-measure1","treat1-measure2",
               "treat2-measure1","treat2-measure2"))
d

  treat1-measure1 treat1-measure2 treat2-measure1 treat2-measure2
1               1               4               2               5
2               2               5               3               4
```

As you can see, we have the same two measure across two treatment for multiple independent runs of the experiment.

I'd like to pivot it to look like this:

```
p <- data.frame(c(1,1,2,2),c(1,2,2,3),c(4,5,5,4))
names(p) <- c("treat","m1","m2")
p

  treat m1 m2
1     1  1  4
2     1  2  5
3     2  2  5
4     2  3  4
```

In the real data, there are only 3 measures and two experimental groups, so a little manual work is doable. Thanks for any help

Comment: You won't be able to avoid parsing the column labels, so start with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a tidyverse approach with `tidyr` with a little help from `tibble`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
d %>% rownames_to_column(var = "index") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = (-index)) %>%
  separate(col = "name", into = c("Treatment","Measure")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("index","Treatment"), names_from = "Measure") %>%
  select(-index)
#  Treatment measure1 measure2
#  <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 treat1           1        4
#2 treat2           2        5
#3 treat1           2        5
#4 treat2           3        4
```

Edit: If anyone ever finds this later, another approach that doesn't rely on creating an index column would be with `unnest`:

```
d %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  separate(col = "name", into = c("Treatment","Measure")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("Treatment"), names_from = "Measure") %>%
  unnest(cols = c("measure1", "measure2"))
## A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Treatment measure1 measure2
#  <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 treat1           1        4
#2 treat1           2        5
#3 treat2           2        5
#4 treat2           3        4
```

Edit 2: I recommend using @akrun's far superior method with the subtly documented `.value` sentinel from `tidyr`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you for saving me hours of pain!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(d), measure = patterns('measure1', 'measure2'), 
     value.name = c('m1', 'm2'), variable.name = 'treat')
#   treat m1 m2
#1:     1  1  4
#2:     1  2  5
#3:     2  2  5
#4:     2  3  4
```

---

Or using a single `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(d, cols = everything(), 
        names_to = c('group', '.value'), names_sep='-')
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  group  measure1 measure2
#  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 treat1        1        4
#2 treat2        2        5
#3 treat1        2        5
#4 treat2        3        4
```